# How to use conditions If / else of compering with Mocha chai (or other tools)

Tags: mocha.js, chai, automation-testing

I have a condition to test.

- If the user is Admin -> exppect admin permissions
- If the user is regular -> expect basic permisiions

But the "expect" ans "should" do not works with conditions and fail after first non admin element

```
if (user.range == 'Admin') {
            expect(user.Permissions, `User ${user.Username} that has range: Admin, should have Admin Permissions`)
                .eql(adminPermissions);
        }
if (user.range == 'Operator') {
            expect(user.Permissions, `User ${user.Username} that has range: Operator, should have Operator Permissions`)
                .eql(operatorPermissions);
        }
```

Comment: Please provide the code under test.

Comment: So is the test failing while it should pass or what is going on? Any error messages?